# Como gerar query e adicionar novo input?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, pdo

Tenho um campo `input` do tipo `date` quero toda vez que eu click e visualizar ele gere um select com a consulta da data que setei e gere um novo input para adicionar outra data e assim por diante.

Meu código ate agora:

HTML FORMULARIO

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" style="margin-left: 10px;" action="#">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="relatorio">Visualizar Relatorio: </label>
 <input type="date" class="form-control" id="relatorio" name="relatorio">
 </div>
 <div class="btn btn-success m-l-10" onclick="consulta()">Adicionar</div>
 <div class="btn btn-success m-l-10" onclick="">Remover</div>
</form>
```

HTML RESULTADOS

```
<table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Cod.</th>
            <th>Descricao</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        foreach ($dia as $b) {?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $b->id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $b->descricao; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $b->status; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $b->valor; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
```

MYSQL:

```
"SELECT *, SUM(valor) as valo FROM pedidos WHERE data LIKE :data GROUP BY `data` ORDER BY id DESC"
```

Meu maior problema e que não sei como gerar os foreach e as querys por que toda vez que adicionar uma uma nova data com os relatórios vai gerar um novo foreach.

Como fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com o PHP não será possível fazer isso "dinamicamente" você terá de lançar os dados através de uma requisição AJAX e cada vez que essa requisição retornar algum valor, ou seja, retornar o HTML, você insere ele com `document.querySelector(".classe");`.

**Edit**
Quando o usuário clicar(configurar) a data, irá lançar a função `connect()`, essa função poderia ser algo do tipo:

```
function connect()
{
    var relatorio = document.getElementById("relatorio").value;
    $.post("query.php", {data: relatorio}, function(response){
        // response é os dados do HTML lá do PHP
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML += response;
    });
}
```

```
query.php
//VOCE PRECISA FAZER O FOREACH NO PHP
//Esse script vai retornar HTML do FOREACH
header("Content-Type", "text/html");

$data = $_POST['data']; //recebendo de $.post (javascript)

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE {$data}"; //faça sua query, porém insira a variável $data

//mande para o banco de dados

//FAÇA O FOREACH AQUI DO HTML E ARMAZENE EM UMA VARIAVEL

//echo $VARIAVEL_COM_O_HTML DO FOREACH
```

EU não sei como deve ser seu resultado final, não sou vidente. Mas está a noção do que voce precisa fazer aí. ATé.

Comment: E como eu faria as querys e os foreach? Sobre AJAX eu sei que teria que entrar porem não sei como gerar as queys e foreach.

Comment: Veja a atualização @EvertonFigueiredo

Comment: Agora acho que consigo só tenho uma duvida rsrs como faço para a variável não se repetir?

Comment: Cara quando eu adicionar o novo input que submeter o novo input o anterior com o dado não sera perdido?

Comment: `...innerHTML += response;` o **+=** aqui pega o que estava antes e soma mais o que vai ser inserido.